# Install window alone

Tags: windows

I have recently added 6 new windows to my house (new holes in the walls). I have also purchased 13 additional new construction windows to replace the old wooden ones. I know the process of replacing them; however, up to this point I have always had an extra set of hands with me. I will have a large chunk of time this weekend to install at least a few windows, but the guys are all unavailable (coincidence?). I would like to at least take a shot at doing the smaller ground level windows.

**Question**: Are there any techniques or processes that could help me in my endeavor to install these new construction windows by myself? My main thoughts are around centering and maintaining appropriate gaps (specifically top and bottom) without having someone on the inside.

I know, silly question, but hoping someone has a tip or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd never do this because of the risk of damaging an expensive window, but if someone forced me, I'd place the window from the outside, loosely fix it in place (in other words, prevent if from falling outwards) with a 2x4 across it (you'll probably need some spacers), then go inside and fiddle with the fit.

Comment: I ended up doing smaller projects today, but I can definitely imagine a rig that jabs into the ground and has a 2x4 cross member helping support the window. I really like this idea! Thanks